# path from fileupload

Tags: c#, file-upload

I am using fileupload control to get the path of the file..
But it gives me some "C:" path instead of the real path of the file..

how can i get the real path of the file uploaded.

I am using :

```
Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName)
```

to get the file path..

but i am getting the path as:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\+filename"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible as it would be a security risk.

It is not clear to me what path you *are* getting, as you should only be getting a file name - you should supply the path to where to save the file.

---

Edit:

You are getting the full path to the file - this shouldn't be happening and doesn't when using most browsers. However, IE does give the full path, even though it is a security hole.

---

Edit 2:

You are using [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) and are supplying the filename only. When this happens, the *current directory* path is perpended to the filename. This would be the directory that your code is running from by default.

From MSDN:

> The file or directory specified by path is not required to exist. For example, if c:\temp\newdir is the current directory, calling GetFullPath on a file name such as test.txt returns c:\temp\newdir\test.txt. The file need not exist.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\+"filename"

Comment: @mucchar - Looks like a path from the _client_, and seeing as you are getting it all, I am assuming you are using IE which incorrectly exposes this data.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a client computer (where the browser lives) and the server computer (where the web server lives)? The path you are getting is coming from the browser (client), though it should not be coming in. IE does give the file path, though it shouldn't - other browsers only give a filename.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that what you're receiving on the server isn't a "file" in the sense of being on a file system.  What you're receiving is a web request.  It contains a header and data which was populated from a file, and you're likely to save it to the file system on the server.  But by the time it comes in as a web request, it's not part of a file system and has no "path" to speak of.

The client would have to send the "path" as part of the request header, which <strike>doesn't</strike> shouldn't happen.